# Spring - custom userDetailsService

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am having issues in using Spring boot with Spring Activiti. we have userDetailsService defined and its working fine with out adding activiti dependency. But with activiti my userDetailsService is getting overridden with root userDetailsService

```
Overriding bean definition for bean '**userDetailsService**' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.partshub.security.UserDetailsService]; .....l; defined in file [C:\GFApps\spring-workspace\Spring-SPA\target\classes\com\partshub\security\UserDetailsService.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration$UserDetailsServiceConfiguration; factoryMethodName=userDetailsService; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/SecurityAutoConfiguration$UserDetailsServiceConfiguration.class]]
```

Maven dependency added

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
        <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
        <version>5.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: try giving different name to your "userDetailsService" bean

Comment: I fixed this by adding below property entry in application.properties    spring.autoconfigure.exclude = "org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration, org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding below property entry fixed my issue

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude = "org.activiti.spring.boot.RestApiAutoConfiguration, org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration"
```